# Difficult to understand the difference between application and abstraction in lambda function

Tags: lambda

I got headache to understand the difference between application and and abstraction
Why λx.x(λx.x) is a abstraction?

Answer (score 0):

The answer follows from the rules (grammar) of lambda calculus, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) for details. Lambda abstraction should have a binder `(λx.?)` on its left hand side. Lambda application has two lambda terms `(M N)` and `M` might not have a binder. `(x x)` is a valid lambda term, which is in normal form and cannot be reduced further.

In our case, the only feasible rule is an abstraction. We rewrite it as `(λx.M)`, where `M := x(λx.x)`. A simple example of the application is `((λx.x)(λx.x))`, where `M := (λx.x)` and `N := (λx.x)`. We reduce it to `(λx.x)`. We may go further and apply abstraction from the question to `(λx.x)`.

```
(λx.x(λx.x))(λx.x) -> (λy.y(λx.x))(λx.x) -> ((λx.x)(λx.x)) -> (λx.x)
```